# For a deceased person, do we use 'the late' or 'late'?

Tags: grammar

When referring to a deceased person, which one of the following is acceptable:

**We, the heirs of *late* John Smith, agree that...**

or

**We, the heirs of *the late* John Smith, agree that...**

Comment: If [this article](http://grammarist.com/usage/the-late/) by Grammarist is anything to go by, then **the late** is the correct usage.

Comment: The need for the definite article depends upon the contextual meaning. *Late* is nothing special and follows the same rules as any other word.

Comment: Please see also [ell.se] Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

*Late* is the correct descriptive adjective to inform the hearer/reader that someone is dead and it always takes *the*.

So *the late Michael Jackson* means "Michael Jackson, who, in case you had forgotten, is dead"

It is not normally used distinctively - that is it is not used to distinguish between one person and another. So you would not say *the late George Bush* to distinguish between the one who has died and his son (who is still alive and is also George Bush).

It is also not used predicatively in UK or US English, so you cannot say *Mr Bush is late*. But this is valid in Indian English.

Comment: Wait, but HW died after you posted this.

Comment: He obviously knew something ;)

Comment: No, Beg to differ with David Robinson. It is not appropriate to refer to the deceased as Mr. Bush is late in Indian English either. Because even in Indian English, it would imply the person has not shown up on time as opposed to the person is dead.

Answer (score 0):

The usage is typically "*the late*." I haven't heard it used without a determiner.

Here are some quotations from the OED's [definition of "late"](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/106050?rskey=oWx6w7&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid) (III.2.a(a)) showing this usage is typical and well-attested (entries with "a" or "my" instead of "the" removed.

> 1838   E. Bulwer-Lytton Alice I. i. vi. 46   I always call **the late Lord Vargrave** my father.
>
> 1989   Q Dec. 149/1   **The late, great talent scout John Hammond**.
>
> 2012   Independent 30 July 21/1   A musical tribute to **the late Amy Winehouse**.